# Portfolio Optimization using causal inferences

Tags: python, causality, causalimpact

I'm trying to use causal inferences in portfolio optimization and I used CausalImpact library in python because it deals with time series. I wanted to check the effect of covid19 on the daily closing prices, so I selected the prior and post period as the period before and after 2019-03-01 respectively.
Since there are no companies that weren't affected by covid19, I used the S&P500 stock market index as the control series. Is this feasible or are there any other alternatives I can use?

Even though I predicted the counterfactual time series as above, I'm confused on how to use causal inferences in portfolio optimization. how can I use these causal inferences on portfolio optimization?

Comment: COVID hit in 2020, not 2019, so you might want to reconsider the date you are using.

Comment: Yes that's a typo, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The index is combination of stocks that were all touched by the pandemic, as you admitted, so it cannot serve as a valid counterfactual.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I use an average daily stock price series of the companies from the same industry, would that be a valid counterfactual?

Comment: @ImalshaUbayawickrema, did they escape the effects of COVID? Probably not, so no.

Comment: If they are in the same industry, then they would be impacted even more similarly. Think about modeling United stock using the other airlines.